# HandlerDelegateは呼び出しでしょうか？

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
public class WebViewActivity(var uri: Uri? = null): DefaultActivity() {

    private class WebViewFragment():
            WebFragment(),
            AdEventHandlerDelegate,
            FavorEventHandlerDelegate,
            ShareEventHandlerDelegate,
            NewPageEventHandlerDelegate,
            LoginPageEventHandlerDelegate,
            LogoutPageEventHandlerDelegate
    {
        private object KeyName {

            val Uri = "Uri"

        }



        public companion object {
            //Function型 fun
            public fun newFragment(uri: Uri): WebViewFragment {

                val fragment = WebViewFragment()

                val args = Bundle()
                args.putString(KeyName.Uri, uri.toString())

                fragment.setArguments(args)

                return fragment

            }

        }

        private fun getWebViewActivity(): WebViewActivity {

            return getActivity() as WebViewActivity

        }

        override fun getEventHandlers(): Collection<EventHandler> {

            return arrayListOf(
                    AdEventHandler(this),
                    FavorEventHandler(this),
                    ShareEventHandler(this),
                    CurrentPageEventHandler(this),
                    NewPageEventHandler(this),
                    LoginPageEventHandler(this),
                    LogoutPageEventHandler(this)
            )

        }
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super<DefaultActivity>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)

        //
        setupUri()

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            val newFragment = WebViewFragment.newFragment(uri!!)

            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.web_view_container, newFragment)
                    .commit()

        }

        getSupportActionBar().hide()

    }

}
```

この場合ですと、   
 val newFragment = WebViewFragment.newFragment(uri!!)
の部分でHandlerDelegateが全て呼び出されているのでしょうか？

EventHandler(this)の部分は何を行っているんでしょうか？

[EventHandlerにWebViewでリクエストをフックして強制的に任意のURLに遷移させる処理を入れることは可能ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12879/webview%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E5%BC%B7%E5%88%B6%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E4%BB%BB%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AEurl%E3%81%AB%E9%81%B7%E7%A7%BB%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javaやandroidの標準クラスでない、実装部分のコードが示されていないAdEventHandlerDelegateのような独自インターフェースの挙動を聞かれても「回答できない」というのが回答になるのではないでしょうか。

他の質問も拝見いたしましたが、質問文で使われている「クラス、メソッド、呼び出し」といった用語を理解されていないように見受けられます。

故に質問の意図が伝わらず、意味不明になっているため、回答が難しくなっているのだと思います。

一度javaやandroid、kotlinの入門サイトや本などで復習するのが近道だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実行という言葉は良くなかったようですね。
分かりやすい質問になるようにしてみます。

val newFragment = WebViewFragment.newFragment(uri!!
の部分はどうやらインターフェイスの実装で、呼び出しは別の場所で行っているようです。